Cannot access disposed objects SignalR .NET 8
In my hub, sometimes the problem described occurs, but I can't intentionally provoke it to demonstrate, but I have read about it and maybe there's a fix as I explain at the end.
So on my Hub I have something like this
namespace auction_hub_base
{

public class Auction_hub_base : Hub<IAuction_hub_base>
{
    private static IDisposable auctionSubscription;

    public Auction_hub_base(IConfiguration config, IAMSLiveEventWrapper ams) : base()
    {
        configuration = config;

        if (auctionSubscription != null)
        {
            auctionSubscription.Dispose();
        }
        auctionSubscription = SingletonReactiveLayer.Auction.Subscribe(state =>
        {
            if (state == null)
            {
                Auction(null);
            }
            else
            {
                // Updated when the method 'Auction.OnNext' is called in singleton
                AuctionResponse res = new AuctionResponse(state.Id, state.EntityId, state.CurrentBatch, state.Finished, state.MaxBidValue);
                Auction(res);
            }
        });
    }
}

public void RegisterConnectionId(int clientId)
{
    SingletonReactiveLayer.RegisterConnectionId(Context.ConnectionId, clientId);
}

public Task Auction(AuctionResponse response)
{
    return Clients.All.Auction(response);
}
}

Then the RegisterConnectionId does something like
public static void RegisterConnectionId(string connId, int clientId)
{
    lock (_auction_SyncRoot)
    {
        if (_auction != null)
        {
            if (!_auction.ClientIds.ContainsKey(clientId))
            {
                _auction.ClientIds.Add(clientId, connId);
            }
            else
            {
                _auction.ClientIds[clientId] = connId;
            }
            Auction.OnNext(_auction);
            Batch.OnNext(_currentBatch);
            // using bid error subscription because here we only need to notify the person who is registering
            BidError.OnNext(_currentBatch?.WinnerBid);

            BatchMessage.OnNext(_batchMessage);
        }
    }
}

And sometimes I get "Cannot access disposed objects" when the code reaches the return Clients.All.Auction(response);.
I saw that the problem could be due to the context and could be solved by injecting it into the constructor and accessing the clients as
return _hubContext.Clients.All.Auction(response);

Can someone give me feedback why this happens?

you have a static IDisposable and you can create multiple instances of the hub_base... why? on a first glance that seems like the perfect cause for your described issue

@Marty I have taken this project from other people and I don't know why they did that. What did you sugest?

And the error its not on the subscription of the static member, it's on the Clients

unfortunately, based only on the code you provided (and also I'm not familiar with the other classes you are using here), I'm mostly in the dark. nonetheless two points: 1. does the change you suggested at the end fix the issue? 2. do you have the ability to run the code in debug mode and also getting the exception there? That way you'll have a better idea what objects are disposed. If you are going for a singleton implementation of a hub base (not sure if that is scalable in all deployments) then look at some already established best practices.

also: just reading the docs says the most important thing: Hubs are transient! So using a static object that's getting disposed the way this code does seems super fishy.
